# C# Window From Autoselects Text

Tags: c#, winforms

I have not dealt with WinForms for a long time.

Now I'm stuck with something trivial but cannot figure it out.

I have a Winform and when a Timer Tick happens I want to show a message in a new form message box:

```
 frmMessage frmM = new frmMessage();
 frmM.txtMessage.Text =  ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Message"];
 frmM.Show();
```

It works but the text in the textbox shows as selected(with a blue background).

I tried

```
txtMessage.SelectionLength = 0;
```

Did not help.

Also tried to set focus to a different control, did not help either.

for now, as a workaround, I will use a Label.

Comment: Where did you call the line to set the SelectionLength to zero? Before or after the frmM.Show line?

Comment: @Steve on Load Event and Tick events.

Comment: Try to use the Shown event

Comment: Both Forms but it did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of the way TextBox Class is implemented.  If a selection is not specifically set, all text will be selected when the control gets focus.

From [TextBox.OnGotFocus](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBox.cs,f6a3d2856dd4ddfe,references):

```
Protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e) {
          base.OnGotFocus(e);
          If (!selectionSet) {
              // We get one shot at selecting when we first get focus.  If we don't
              // do it, we still want to act Like the selection was set.
              selectionSet = true;

              // If the user didn't provide a selection, force one in.
              If (SelectionLength == 0 && Control.MouseButtons == MouseButtons.None) {
                  SelectAll();
              }
          }
```

Additionally due to the way the [SelectionLength Property](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase.cs,058f568b2ecb4c89,references) is implemented, setting that property to zero does not set the selectionSet` flag as it is already zero.

Instead, set the TextBox.SelectionStart Property immediately after setting the text as this will set that flag.

```
txtMessage.SelectionStart = 0;
```

However, your *work-a-round* of using a `Label` to display a message is much more appropriate than using an input control.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best answer but it works. You can try this

```
frmMessage frmM = new frmMessage();
frmM.txtMessage.Text = "";
frmM.txtMessage.AppendText(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Message"]);
frmM.Show();
```